# Ways to Improve Extremely Slow Codeigniter Website

Tags: html, performance, codeigniter

I'm experiencing a **very slow loading on my website**.

At first I thought that maybe my code is slow, but after comparing my previous work to the same work, but migrating it to codeigniter I can say that the loading is now significantly slower.

Do you have any suggestion or ways to improve the performance of codeigniter?

Comment: i would say have a look at pagespeed and yslow to improve your server settings and some code issues regarding html. generally, codeigniter is a rather fast framework. Also, before migrating, consider that the development of codeigniter seems to be paused, somewhat. Thats why i am currently migrating my CI-projects to laravel.

Comment: Thanks nozzleman, yeah I've also think about that because CI is now looking for a new owner. Thanks for suggesting pagespeed and yslow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> improve the performance of codeigniter

Performance depends slightly on framework, CI itself is one of the fastest.

Your project performance mostly depends on your code, how you use PHP, how you create queries and maintain JS code.

Short answer to your question:

1. CI active record class is garbage, use classic queries / alternative PDO.
2. Use advantage of condition-loading helpers/modules
3. Don't use security class functions unless it's necessary
4. Study config files, there is much you can disable to speed up.

This can help, may not, best way to avoid performance problems is to study how languages work, for example you can get valuable performance info [about PHP here](http://www.phpbench.com/).

Comment: why do u say CI active record class is garbage?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

1. Compress HTML output, [like this](https://gist.github.com/abedputra/2d2527304019ee54b1f2548598d34340)

2. Cache functions

```
$this->output->cache(60); // Will expire in 60 minutes
```

3. Enable Gzip Compression

```
$config['compress_output'] = TRUE;
```